# make window transparent with SDL_SetWindowOpacity in sdl

Tags: ubuntu, sdl

Now I can make window transparent with SDL_SetWindowOpacity.

screenshot:
[SDL_SetWindowOpacity work on my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG5rK.png)

However I want only to make backgroud become tansparent,the text on the Window shoud be opaque.

transparent background/opaque foreground

Answer (score 3):

1. "transparent background" as in *completely* transparent for some subset of window pixels: [`SDL_CreateShapedWindow()`](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/9dad1513547b/include/SDL_shape.h#l66) and friends from [`SDL_shape.h`](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/9dad1513547b/include/SDL_shape.h), i.e. [shapes (X11)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_extension)/[regions (Win32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162915(v=vs.85).aspx).
2. "transparent background" as in partially translucent: [`SDL_SetWindowOpacity()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowOpacity) from [`SDL_video.h`](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/default/include/SDL_video.h)

Comment: All thing become transparent, but I hope background is transparent and other elements on window are opacity.         transparent background/opacity foreground

Comment: Were you able to achieve this? I was looking for this solution too, but never found one. If you were able to figure this out please share the solution.